# Getting Azure AD SSO to work with two differents URLs

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

We have an application that is reachable through a specific URL when connected from our office public IP, and that is reachable through another specific URL when outside the office with a VPN.

We managed to set up the oAuth2 SSO for the first usecase and I was wondering if there was any way to add the second URL, so that our users working through the VPN could also log in with the SSO.

Couldn't find a way to do it so far, if you have any clue.

Thanks !

Comment: You can add multiple reply urls / redirect URIs. Your app needs to decide which one should be used though on every login

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept my reply as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSvbC.png).

Answer (score 0):

As juunas said, when you set Redirect URIs in Azure App registration, you could add multiple redirect urls.

[image]

And when you use OAuth2 SSO, here such as [using OpenID Connect flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-the-sign-in-request), you could **specify different redirect_uri** when you authenticate the user.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept my reply as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, the second redirect URI configured in the Azure App was redirecting us to the first one specified, after hitting the SSO connection button. I guess we found something in the app that was forcing this redirection, we'll try to remove this setting on Monday.

Thanks for you help,
Steven